# How to add object to the array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

```
type Student struct {
    ID           primitive.ObjectID   `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    ...
    Users      []primitive.ObjectID `json:"users"`
    ...
}
```

I have this struct and I want to add to `Users array`. I'm doing this and I'm using `Mongo-go-driver`

```
// Filter for search
filter := bson.M{"_id": userID}

// Fields to update
update := bson.M{"$addToSet": bson.M{"users": ID}}

// Update the document
UsersCollection := GetUsersCollection()
UsersCollection.FindOneAndUpdate(context.Background(), filter, update, nil)
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? It's not adding to the database it's staying null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change suggestions:

1. Change structure metadata tag `json` to `bson`

```
type Student struct {
    ID           primitive.ObjectID   `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    ...
    Users      []primitive.ObjectID   `bson:"users"`
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's not working. I did this `var values = []primitive.ObjectID{ID}`

Comment: @VarunRaj have you tried using single  value like your example? that also failed?